# jQuery animate background color. Remove Math.random

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I want to animate between an array of background colors.

I found the following code, but it uses **Math.random** to display the background colors in random order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    setInterval(function() {
        var theColours = Array('#ffffff','#000000','#00ff00','#ff0000','#0000ff');
        var theColour = theColours[Math.floor(Math.random()*theColours.length)];
        $('#branding').animate({backgroundColor: theColour}, 500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvanstan/wxxrd2sv/)

I want to remove the **Math.random** and display the next color in the array.

However, if I replace **Math.random**, with the following, the animation doesn't proceed beyond the first color in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    setInterval(function() {
        var theColours = Array('#ffffff','#000000','#00ff00','#ff0000','#0000ff');
        var currentColour = 0;
        var theColour = theColours[Math.floor(currentColour++ % theColours.length)];
        $('#branding').animate({backgroundColor: theColour}, 500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `currentColour` is declared inside your `setInterval` function, you are creating a new `currentColour` variable and setting it to `0` each time the function is called. Instead move `currentColour` outside the function scope:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentColour = 0; // This variable is now shared by each function call
    setInterval(function() {
        var theColours = Array('#ffffff','#000000','#00ff00','#ff0000','#0000ff');
        var theColour = theColours[Math.floor(currentColour++ % theColours.length)];
        $('#branding').animate({backgroundColor: theColour}, 500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you re-initializing 'theColour' in the code itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var currentColour = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var theColours = Array('#ffffff','#000000','#00ff00','#ff0000','#0000ff');            
        var theColour = theColours[Math.floor(currentColour++ % theColours.length)];
        $('#branding').animate({backgroundColor: theColour}, 500);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the **currentColour** out of function setInterval

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var currentColour = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        var theColours = Array('#ffffff','#000000','#00ff00','#ff0000','#0000ff');
        var theColour = theColours[Math.floor(currentColour++ % theColours.length)];
        $('#branding').animate({backgroundColor: theColour}, 500);
    }, 1000);
});
```